# API to know Azure Notification Hubs limit left

Tags: azure, push-notification

I need to know how to get limit which is left for Azure Notification Hub. Is there such function in Azure API? I haven't find anything about it in docs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are three tiers in Notification Hubs—free, basic, and standard. Base charge and quotas are applied at the namespace level. These three tiers have limits in the namespace. For more details, you can refer to the [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/). To see the current namespace tier, simply GET on the namespace plan:

```
GET: https://management.core.windows.net/{subscription ID}/services/ServiceBus/Namespaces/{namespace name}/notificationhubplan
```

Comment: If you’re a Microsoft partner, I recommend you visiting aka.ms/devchat for personalized support on Azure. It’s free and 24x5.